# How to run rake task with parameter in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake

I want to run rake task from my rspec by passing parameter. I tried without passing parameter, it works fine. But by passing parameter it throws

```
`RuntimeError (Don't know how to build task 'user_details:address[2]'):
```

this rake command works fine in command line

```
rake user_details:address[2]
```

In my rspec

```
require 'rake'
Rake::Task["user_details:address[#{user_id}]"].invoke
```

How to run this task from rspec?

Comment: try this: @rake = Rake::Application.new; Rake.application = @rake;   Rake::Task.define_task(:environment); @rake["user_details:address[#{user_id}]"].invoke

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev still getting the same error. I don't know where that "')" is appending in my task name

Comment: aha, turns out that test environment doesn't load files in lib. You have to manually load them at the top of the file, like so: load File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'lib', 'tasks', 'my_task.rake')

Comment: did you try this one? include it after require 'rake'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass the arguments to `invoke`:

```
Rake::Task["user_details:address"].invoke(user_id)
```

Comment: I am getting the same error after passing parameter in invoke

Comment: @Achaius It shouldn't raise the same error if there are any. Did you remove the `[#{user_id}]` part?

Comment: the problem is extra ') appended at the end of my task name. I don't know from where its getting append

Comment: Does the problem get fixed now? Or are there still any errors?